# How to do different update queries based on different failures happening in 2 different service activaters?

Tags: spring-integration

**xml comfiguration of spring -integration**

```html
<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter id="inchannel"
  query="query the db" data-source="dataSource" max-rows-per-poll="1"
  update="update query">
  <int:poller fixed-rate="8000">
   <int:transactional />
  </int:poller>
 </int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>


<bean id="sp" class="main.poll" />

 <int:channel id="ec">
  <int:dispatcher task-executor="taskExecutor" />
 </int:channel>


 <task:executor id="taskExecutor" pool-size="2" />

 <int:service-activator input-channel="inchannel"
  output-channel="ecl" ref="sp" method="grpe">
  <int:request-handler-advice-chain>
   <int:retry-advice recovery-channel="errorchannel" />
  </int:request-handler-advice-chain>
 </int:service-activator>

 <int:service-activator input-channel="ec" ref="sp"
  method="gdl">
      <int:request-handler-advice-chain>
   <int:retry-advice recovery-channel="errorchannel"/>
        </int:request-handler-advice-chain>
 </int:service-activator>
```

"ec" is an executer channel which gets the output from "inchannel"."ec" is the input-channel of the 2nd service activater.
Scenario : After all the 3 retries failed for 1st service i want to do an update query.Also after 3 retries for the 2nd service activater,i want to do another different update query.This is not possible since i have only one inbound adapter..Can i handle it with spring-integration ?I just want to **do different update queries based on different failures happening in my 2 service activaters**..can anyone please help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this purpose you should use `<int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter>` with desired `UPDATE` on that `recovery-channel`. One update for one `<service-activator>`, another update and channel, too, for another `<service-activator>`.

Otherwise your question isn't clear.

Please, elaborate more on this, too:

> This is not possible since i have only one inbound adapter.

If you mean that `update="update query"` on the `<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>`, you can't change it. It's a bit breaking concept for the messaging architecture. The polling endpoint must finish its work before emitting messages to the channel. I mean that `UPDATE` is done in the `JdbcPollingChannelAdapter` just after the `SELECT` and before sending message to the `inchannel`. You don't have control over there in the downstream flow.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me on the concept of UPDATE in inbound adapter.I don't need an update query there.Is UPDATE supported on <int-service activator> or in the recovery channel ?should i use anything extra like endpoints ?

Comment: You should use separate endpoint - `<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>` for `UPDATE`. And your `recovery-channel` is a good point to go ahead after retry exhausting.

Comment: so i should use 2 jdbc outbound adapters for 2 service activaters each ?